# Join two column trivially in R

Tags: r

I want to join two tables one with old product and rank data and the second with few updated ranks for some product in the first table.

EG: (say)

```
table 1-

Product    Rank 
a           32     
b           21
c           14
d           36
e            1

table 2-

Product   Rank
b          7
d          8
```

I want the output table to look like:

```
Product    Rank
a           32
b            7
c           14
d            8
e            1
```

TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with base R:

```r
rbind(table1[!table1$Product %in% table2$Product, ], table2)
#>    Product Rank
#> 1        a   32
#> 3        c   14
#> 5        e    1
#> 11       b    7
#> 2        d    8
```

Or, by assignment:

```
table1[table1$Product %in% table2$Product, ] <- table2

table1
#>   Product Rank
#> 1       a   32
#> 2       b    7
#> 3       c   14
#> 4       d    8
#> 5       e    1
```

data

```
table1 <- read.table(text =
"Product    Rank 
a           32     
b           21
c           14
d           36
e            1", header = TRUE)

table2 <- read.table(text =
                       "Product   Rank
b          7
d          8", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: bro in your case product names also got replaced with serial numbers

Comment: @AliBaba nope, simply the order changed (only in the first example), the data is the same as in your desired output. What you call serial numbers are row numbers. You can ignore them.

Comment: The serial numbers is replacing my product name itself. b and d is becoming 1 and 2.

Comment: @AliBaba This is difficult to reproduce, please provide snippets of your real data. You can do that with using `dput(head(table1))` and `dput(head(table2))` and please post the entire output of both calls

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and assuming your tables are data.frames named `df` and `df2`:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="Product") %>%
  mutate(Rank=coalesce(Rank.y, Rank.x)) %>%
  select(-Rank.x, -Rank.y)
```

yields

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Product  Rank
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 a          32
2 b           7
3 c          14
4 d           8
5 e           1
```

Comment: Error in list2(...) : object 'Rank.y' not found